# При вводе l = 1500 и выборе n = 4 программа выводит 0,0000. В чем проблема?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    int n = 1;
    double l;

    printf("Введите длину отрезка: ");
    scanf("%d", &l);

    do
    {
        printf("Введите единицу измерения длины, где \n1 - дециметр,\n2 - километр,\n3 - метр,\n4 - миллиметр,\n5 - сантиметр \n");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        switch(n)
        {
        case 1: printf("Длина отрезка - %lf метров. \n", l/10.0); break;
        case 2: printf("Длина отрезка - %d метров. \n", l*10); break;
        case 3: printf("Длина отрезка - %d метров. \n", l); break;
        case 4: printf("Длина отрезка - %lf метров. \n", l/1000.0); break;
        case 5: printf("Длина отрезка - %lf метров. \n", l/100.0); break;
        default: printf("Ошибка. Повторите ввод. \n");
        }
    }
    while (n>5 || n < 1);

    system("pause");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: А почему вы не пользуетесь отладчиком?

Comment: @VladD, а им многие не любят пользоваться :D

Comment: @VladD не умею им пользоваться т.к пишу в Dev C++.

Comment: А что, отладочный вывод уже отменили? Или вы считаете, что первое, что было написано для какого-нибудь ЭНИАКа - это отладчик?

Comment: @Harry Спасибо за совет! Впредь придётся им пользоваться, раз допускаю такие нелепые ошибки.

Comment: Это не связано с нелепостью ошибок :) Сам постоянно пользуюсь. Получается часто быстрее, чем в отладчике :)

Comment: *"Dev C++"* -- а с какой версии там пропала возможность отлаживаться прямо в IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка была в данной строке:

```
scanf("%d", &l);
```

Переменной **l** типа **double** был присвоен спецификатор **%d.** -___-

Comment: У вас и в `printf` аналогичные ошибки, о чём, кстати, и компилятор обычно сообщает.

Comment: @zed Спасибо, исправил.